# Ansible : multiline variable containing pipe

Tags: ansible, ascii-art

I try to make an Ansible role to create MOTD (message of the day) on Linux server.

I want to add ASCII art in this file, ASCII art is defined in a variable used in my template.

So my ASCII art variable need to be multiline and contain multiple special character.

I try:

```
motd_asciiart: |
     _____ _             _                        __ _               
    /  ___| |           | |                      / _| |              
    \ `--.| |_ __ _  ___| | _______   _____ _ __| |_| | _____      __
     `--. \ __/ _` |/ __| |/ / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__|  _| |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
    /\__/ / || (_| | (__|   < (_) \ V /  __/ |  | | | | (_) \ V  V / 
    \____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/ \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/
```

But I've got this error:

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>
> The error appears to have been in '/Users/ydavid/Devops/ansible2/roles/umanit.motd/defaults/main.yml': line 3, column 9, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>      _____ _             _                        __ _
>     /  ___| |           | |                      / _| |
>     ^ here
> ```

I try to add " on the first and last line, I've got a different error :

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>
> The error appears to have been in '/Users/ydavid/Devops/ansible2/roles/umanit.motd/defaults/main.yml': line 7, column 74, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>     /\__/ / || (_| | (__|   < (_) \ V /  __/ |  | | | | (_) \ V  V /
>     \____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/ \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/ "
>                                                                     ^ here
> ```

Can you help me?

Can we escape a whole block?

I found this role (https://github.com/picotrading/ansible-motd) which make the same thing but ASCII art is one-lined, if I can I will to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is indentation - the second line starts one space earlier than in the first one, which is a reference point.

I guess the cleanest solution would be to save the art to a separate file and read the content using [`file_contents` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins):

```
vars:
  motd_asciiart: "{{lookup('file', './art.txt')}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
With this solution how can I use a different file for my host ?
I need one generic file and some exception for specific hosts

Comment: Sure. I don't see how this relates to the original question though. You can use host_vars, group_vars, or include the file based on the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing spaces with dots. It worked for me.

```yaml
motd_asciiart: |
....._____._............._........................__._...............
..../..___|.|...........|.|....................../._|.|..............
....\.`--.|.|_.__._..___|.|._______..._____._.__|.|_|.|._____......__
.....`--..\.__/._`.|/.__|.|/./._.\.\././._.\.'__|.._|.|/._.\.\./\././
..../\__/./.||.(_|.|.(__|...<.(_).\.V./..__/.|..|.|.|.|.(_).\.V..V./.
....\____/.\__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/.\_/.\___|_|..|_|.|_|\___/.\_/\_/..
```